# Stack multiple images using ImageMagick with solid background

Tags: cmd, imagemagick

How do I stack more than two images on top of each other, while setting the background color at the same time? The width/height of the final image should be auto calculated, which i believe Mosaic does. But i can't figure out how to this using cmd line args?

In this case i want to stack 3 images and make the background this color using a hex value #ff0000

```
"C:/User/magick.exe" composite C:/User/image01.png C:/User/image02.png C:/User/image03.png C:/User/combined/combined.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use simply magick, not magick composite in ImageMagick.

```
magick image1 image2 -background "#ff0000" -mosaic result
```

This puts image2 over image1 over the background with the two images aligned at the top left corner. If you want offsets, use -page.

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#mosaic